Install a specific version of a package
this is my vcpkg.json file.
{
    "dependencies": ["boost","hiredis","nlohmann-json","spdlog","fmt","libpq","librdkafka","curl"],
    "overrides": [
        { "name": "boost", "version": "1.83.0" },
        { "name": "hiredis", "version": "1.0.0" },
        { "name": "nlohmann-json", "version": "3.11.3" },
        { "name": "spdlog", "version": "1.14.1"},
        { "name": "fmt", "version": "10.2.1" },
        { "name": "libpq", "version": "16.2" },
        { "name": "librdkafka", "version": "2.3.0" },
        { "name": "curl", "version": "8.7.1" }
    ],
    "builtin-baseline": "3426db05b996481ca31e95fff3734cf23e0f51bc"
}

when i try to the command vcpkg install --triplet x64-windows getting error error: unexpected switch: --manifest

Is your version of vcpkg ancient? Are you executing the command from the same directory as the manifest file? I also don't think you need to specify the triplet unless you intend to cross-compile.

updated vcpkg, and yeah same directory.

Have you tried specifying your versions when listing your dependencies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/versioning.concepts

I'm less familiar with the "overrides" key, but I know you can specify your version numbers with the dependencies.
